# Laravel 6: Fetching data from multiple pivot tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a funds table that contains funds that are associated with different faculties, institutes, initiatives etc. A fund belongs to many faculties and faculties could have many funds.

I also have a many to many relationship between users and faculty table to make sure that a user can only see the funds associated with specific faculties.

```
funds table
--------------------
  id
  name
  ...

faculties table
--------------------
  id
  name
  ...

faculties_funds table
---------------------
  id
  faculty_id
  fund_id

users table
---------------------
  id
  fname
  ...

faculties_user
--------------------
  id
  faculty_user
  user_id
```

Here is how I have defined my relationships:

```
class Fund extends Model
{
  public function faculties(){
        return $this -> belongsToMany('App\Faculty');
    }
}

class Faculty extends Model
{
  public function funds(){
        return $this -> belongsToMany('App\Fund');
    }
  public function users(){
        return $this -> belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}

class User extends Model{
  public function faculties(){
        return $this -> belongsToMany('App\Faculty');
    }
}
```

What I need is to be able to fetch all the funds associated with the faculty that the authorized user is mapped to. I tested the relationships individually and they all work and I can dd the response that also has a relationship array with pivot information but I am somehow not able to get the funds that I want.

Any help would be appreciated in terms of writing a query to get the results preferably without using the raw queries or if I need to redo my database structure.

Here is my code so far:

```
public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if(Auth::user() -> role == 'superadmin'){
            return view('funds.index')
                    -> with('funds', Fund::all());
        }else{
            dd( Auth::user() -> faculties); //I can see the faculties associated and also 
            dd( Auth::user() -> faculties() -> funds ); //doesnt work
        }
    }
```

[DD Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7S0A.png)

Comment: I think you should check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) or [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through)

Comment: I'm surprised your relationship are working as standard table naming convention is not respected

Comment: @ADELNAMANI - thanks for pointing me to this, Never used it before. My relationships aren't defined using pivots but for the future, I will look into it and implement it in a more streamlined fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table naming convention is not as per what Laravel expects: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

This modified code should return your funds as expected:

```
class Faculty extends Model
{
  public function funds(){
        return $this -> belongsToMany('App\Fund', 'faculties_funds', 'falculty_id', 'fund_id');
    }
}

class User extends Model{
  public function faculties(){
        return $this -> belongsToMany('App\Faculty','faculties_user');
    }
}
```

And then call

```
dd(Auth::user()->with('faculties.funds');
```

Comment: I cleaned up the naming conventions, apparently one of them was causing an issue with fetching the data. THANK YOU SIR